# How to set Qalculator as default calculator?

Tags: 13.10, default-programs

I am trying to set which calculator will be called when I press the calculator button on the keyboard. My favourite calc app is Qalculate.

How can I set it be the default one so I can open it via calc button on my keyboard?

Comment: the exact same question was asked [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411504)

Comment: @wilf Thanks. I posted my solution for further reference and help to others.

Comment: I didn't add the smiley - :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it following the link in [this comment by @Wilf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398041/how-to-set-qalculator-as-default-calculator/398049#comment510103_398041) to [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411504)

Ubuntu 13.10 uses the calculator tool `gnome-caculator`. So instead of messing with the system, the easiest is to fake this shortcut with a symbolic link bound to `qalculator` tool.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-calculator /usr/bin/gnome-calculator_original
sudo ln -sT /usr/bin/qalculate /usr/bin/gnome-calculator
```

The shortcut works instantly.

Comment: Upgrading `gnome-calculator` may cause this to break by overwriting the symlink with an upgraded version of `gnome-calculator`. Updating a keyboard shortcut that goes directly to `qalculate` is recommended instead.

Answer (score 8):

I came here to find an answer which doesn't include moving around executables and creating links. Then realized that the answer is actually very simple and obvious:

Go to [settings](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings) and create a custom key binding for whichever calculator app you want and calc key. Let it disable the old one. And that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

The best option IMHO is to redefine the keybinding of the <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key, just as @user58635 said.

In order to make it more programatically, for example to include in a script to be executed after a new installation, these steps may be useful for more than one:

1. Set the current binding to none:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys calculator ''
   ```

   - Or you can set it to another keybinding, e.g. pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Calculator</kbd>:

     ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys calculator '<Shift>Calculator'
     ```
2. Create a new custom keybinding for the Calculator key<sup>1</sup>:

   1. If you have no other custom keybinding:

      ```
      # Create a new set of custom keybindings
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"

      # Set the new custom keybinding (key, command, name)
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding 'Calculator'
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'qalculate-gtk'
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'Qalculate'
      ```
   2. If you already have some custom keybinding in operation, you must add this as another one. For example:

      ```
      # Create a new set of custom keybindings
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']"

      # Set the first custom keybinding (key, command, name)
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding 'Launch5'
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'iceweasel -ProfileManager -no-remote'
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'Iceweasel'

      # Set the second (new) custom keybinding (key, command, name)
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding 'Calculator'
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command 'qalculate-gtk'
      gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name 'Qalculate'
      ```
3. If nothing happens at first try, just restart Gnome. In Gnome Shell it is just <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then press <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

References:

<sup>1: Take this excellent answer as advice: https://askubuntu.com/a/597414/17564</sup>