# How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal for different Linux versions?

Basically I want to know where Linux stores the keyboard shortcut files and how it can be edited.

On my research I found a file `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig` but it was more or like encrypted when I tried to open it with `nano`.

Comment: Note, XFCE/Xubuntu systems already have an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90513/how-do-i-change-my-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xubuntu/760958#760958)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### Adding shortcut keybindings in two steps from the command line (14.04+)

Adding custom shortcuts from the command line can be done, but is a bit complicated; it needs to be done in a few steps per keybinding. On the other hand, it *is* pretty straightforward and can very well be scripted if you somehow want to do it from the command line (that was the question, right?).

Just like in your interface (System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"), Custom keyboard shortcuts are made from command line in two steps:

1. create the keybinding by editing (adding to-) the list that is returned by the command:

   ```
   gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
   ```

   The returned list looks like (if it were only one shortcut currently):

   ```
   ['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']
   ```

   Apply the edited list by the command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "[<altered_list>]"
   ```

   (mind the double quotes)

   **N.B.** No need to say that the mention in the list (e.g. `custom1`, `custom2`) should be a unique one. If you script it, the script should prevent duplicates. In this case the edited list should look like e.g.:

   ```
   ['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']
   ```

   to add one keybinding: `custom1`
2. set its properties:

   - name:

     ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name '<newname>'
     ```
   - command:

     ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command '<newcommand>'
     ```
   - Key combination (for example `<Primary><Alt>g`):

     ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding '<key_combination>'
     ```

Useful information can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings)

#### Example script to set a new custom shortcut

The script below can be used to set a new shortcut key combination from the command line. It can be used with the command (assuming the key combination is available):

```
python3 /path/to/script.py '<name>' '<command>' '<key_combination>'
```

*An example:*

To set a shortcut key combination to open `gedit` with the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py 'open gedit' 'gedit' '<Alt>7'
```

*The script:*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

# defining keys & strings to be used
key = "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings"
subkey1 = key.replace(" ", ".")[:-1]+":"
item_s = "/"+key.replace(" ", "/").replace(".", "/")+"/"
firstname = "custom"
# get the current list of custom shortcuts
get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
array_str = get("gsettings get "+key)
# in case the array was empty, remove the annotation hints
command_result = array_str.lstrip("@as")
current = eval(command_result)
# make sure the additional keybinding mention is no duplicate
n = 1
while True:
    new = item_s+firstname+str(n)+"/"
    if new in current:
        n = n+1
    else:
        break
# add the new keybinding to the list
current.append(new)
# create the shortcut, set the name, command and shortcut key
cmd0 = 'gsettings set '+key+' "'+str(current)+'"'
cmd1 = 'gsettings set '+subkey1+new+" name '"+sys.argv[1]+"'"
cmd2 = 'gsettings set '+subkey1+new+" command '"+sys.argv[2]+"'"
cmd3 = 'gsettings set '+subkey1+new+" binding '"+sys.argv[3]+"'"

for cmd in [cmd0, cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

*How to use:*

Paste the script into an empty file, save it as `set_customshortcut.py`, run it as explained above.

#### Some of the mostly used key mentions (found experimentally, looking into the changes the GUI way made into the binding value):

```
Super key:                 <Super>
Control key:               <Primary> or <Control>
Alt key:                   <Alt>
Shift key:                 <Shift>
numbers:                   1 (just the number)
Spacebar:                  space
Slash key:                 slash
Asterisk key:              asterisk (so it would need `<Shift>` as well)
Ampersand key:             ampersand (so it would need <Shift> as well)

a few numpad keys:
Numpad divide key (`/`):   KP_Divide
Numpad multiply (Asterisk):KP_Multiply
Numpad number key(s):      KP_1
Numpad `-`:                KP_Subtract
```

etc.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Could you please explain a little on the **Key combination** part? What does that <primary> tag indicate? And instead of letter **g** I can replace any letter I think,ryt?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thats Okey. But now I have a small issue. When I try to set a new custom say `custom1` as u mentioned, I get an error saying `expected ',' or ']' to follow array element:`. Could you please tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: This was the command I ran-
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "[['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']]"`.

Initially I had only custom0. Then I tried to add cutom1 with that. And the error was `expected ',' or ']' to follow array element:` along with the list I tried to enter.

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus You are right! I didn't notice this comment before for some reason. Maybe we should remove the comments by now :)

Comment: Any reason why these commands would not work on a Xubuntu 14.04 computer?

Comment: @VladK ai, xubuntu, could be that xubuntu's shortcuts are (still) set in an xml file. I will have to look. If so, we need to reopen your question, tagged as xubuntu- specific.

Comment: @JacobVlijm you are the man. It would be under a .gconf folder in that case, correct?

Comment: @VladK look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/557084/any-way-to-open-windows-from-the-windows-bar-using-a-shortcut, it also describes where the shortcuts are set. I will vote to reopen your question.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/nappa300/Keybind/tree/master/gsettings)  is a C implementation of your script @JacobVlijm.  (Was sure it would work on Xubuntu and didn't even test if gsettings would effect my system before finishing the script. Works well though. Making a solution for Xubuntu now.)

Comment: I wrote [a Bash script](http://pastebin.com/gv1xJSdR) that finds the current configuration of custom shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you, @JacobVlijm, I've tried it out. And i just find out that my fix was a mistake. There is some really tricky here.  `custom-keybinding` shouldn't contain "s" at the end when inside a schema. But, it should contain "s" when act as key or in path. Otherwise, the "set" command will throw exception. So, please remove the "s" of `custom-keybinding` in schema. Besides, your python script should update too.

Comment: @SaintScott just tested the script, works like a charm on 16.04. What error do you get?

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name` that's what i figured out. Do you have other solutions? If so, i will open another issue for you. ^.^

Comment: @SaintScott yeah, I've got another one, where you can simply use the schortcut *name*  (custom shortcuts only). I will have to leave in about 20 minutes, but got the answer ready to paste :)

Comment: How can I automate this process? Like this `bind -x '"\C-p":git status'`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/748963/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-terminal-command  I want to add only command and shortkey, then the system automatically set this.

Comment: It won't work for me as it is with more than one command. However, if I remove the space in the list. That is `['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']` -> `['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/','/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']` it works flawlessly. Same with the script

Comment: gsettings didn't work for me at all. It's not setting the shortkey neither showing the shortkeys I set from settings. dconf on the other hand worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 20):

There is plain a simple way of doing that using `dconf` :

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/command "'move-window.sh'"
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding "'<Primary><Alt>Page_Down'"
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/name "'move-window'"
```

Using `gsettings` :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name "'move-window'"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding "'<Primary><Alt>Page_Down'"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command "'/usr/local/bin/move-window.sh'"
```

You need to increase number in the `custom0`part for adding more bindings, ie. `custom1`, `custom2`, etc.

To make it permanent, just add it to `.bash_profile` or a similar script that is ran by login shells. Just don't do it for non-login shells `.bashrc` because from my experience these `dconf` and `gsettings` slow it down significantly. Changing/Adding 30 bindings  takes a second ! You don't want this in non-login shell (`.bashrc`)!

Comment: Both fail in Ubuntu 18.04. Following @Jacob Vlijm's answer and [this community wiki](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1171), you need to add `custom0` to the custom shortcut list, e.g. with `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['.../custom1/']"`. I don't know about `dconf`.

Comment: Also [`dconf dump DIR`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dconf.1.html) to _Dump an entire subpath to stdout. The output is in a keyfile-like format, with values in GVariant syntax._

Answer (score 10):

All the custom keyboard shortcuts settings are stored in the dconf database.

You can easily access them with `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then go to the following dconf path in the editor:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/
```

[image]

Comment: Is the location same for all versions of Linux? Or atleast all the versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus: this is the location of the settings since 14.04 (I can't tell for other distro)

Comment: This is graphical method, and not from terminal

Comment: What do I do if my media-keys key does not have a custom-keybindings subkey?

Comment: The question was about terminal, not GUI, so answer is irrelevant

Answer (score 6):

#### Adding shortcut keybindings from the command line in 12.04

To prevent the accepted answer to become too extensive, posting a separate solution for 12.04.

Until (and including) 12.04, custom keybindings are not stored in the `dconf` database, but in `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/keybindings` (in an xml file, in subfolders like `custom0` etc).

The script below creates the `xml` file and its containg folder, automatically named correctly.

#### How to use

1. Paste the script into an empty file, save it as `set_customshortcuts_12.py`
2. Run it with the command:

   ```
   python /path/to/set_customshortcuts_12.py <name> <command> <key1> <key2> <key3>
   ```

   `key3` is optional, commands can be for example:

   ```
   python /path/to/set_customshortcuts_12.py run_browser firefox Primary 7
   ```

   or

   ```
   python /path/to/set_customshortcuts_12.py run_texteditor gedit Primary Alt 3
   ```

#### Notes

- note that the naming of the keys is different from editing gsettings. The keys are named like they show in System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts", as far as I can see.
- I tested the script on 12.04 under VirtualBox; it needed a log out/in for the changes to take place.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

home = os.environ["HOME"]
name = sys.argv[1]
command = sys.argv[2]
keys = sys.argv[3:]

keyfile = [
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
    '<gconf>',
    '\t<entry name="action" mtime="1427791732" type="string">',
    '\t\t<stringvalue>'+command+'</stringvalue>',
    '\t</entry>',
    '\t<entry name="name" mtime="1427791732" type="string">',
    '\t\t<stringvalue>'+name+'</stringvalue>',
    '\t</entry>',
    '\t<entry name="binding" mtime="1427791736" type="string">',
    '\t</entry>',
    '</gconf>',
    ]

if len(keys) == 2:
    keyfile.insert(9, '\t\t<stringvalue>&lt;'+keys[0]+'&gt;'+keys[1]+'</stringvalue>')
else:
    keyfile.insert(9, '\t\t<stringvalue>&lt;'+keys[0]+'&gt;&lt;'+keys[1]+'&gt;'+keys[2]+'</stringvalue>')

n = 0
while True:
    check = home+"/"+".gconf/desktop/gnome/keybindings/custom"+str(n)
    if os.path.exists(check):
        n = n+1
    else:
        newdir = check
        newfile = check+"/"+"%gconf.xml"
        break

os.makedirs(newdir)
with open(newfile, "wt") as shortcut:
    for l in keyfile:
        shortcut.write(l+"\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

### Save custom keyboard shortcuts

You can save/backup/export custom shortcuts/keybidings using just [`dconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dconf.1.html) and `sed`

#### Export

```bash
dconf dump / | sed -n '/\[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys/,/^$/p' > custom-shortcuts.ini # Export
```

#### Import

```bash
dconf load / < custom-shortcuts.ini # Import
```

---

- To backup you might want to use `custom-shortcuts-$(date -I).ini`
- Note that `dconf` [by default reads the user-db](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html) and only dumps non-default values (bold in `dconf-editor`)
- Only for the added custom shortcuts
- Based on [Ciro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746262/349837) (also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093110/349837))
- Test if it's working by [resetting to defaults](https://askubuntu.com/a/315226/349837) this path before importing

  ```
  gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
  ```
- The same way you can backup for example a [GNOME Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/) setup:

  ```
  dconf dump / | sed -n '/\[org.gnome.shell.extensions.system-monitor\]/,/^$/p' > extensions-system-monitor-$(date -I).conf
  ```

Comment: Instead of using sed to grep for media-keys, it's probably better  to dump the path directly via `dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/`

Comment: @bk138 Test and compare them. [They are not the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal/1200953?noredirect=1#comment1910569_826328).

Comment: What an under-rated answer! Simple, useful, well explained, well tested. Wish I could upvote you twice.

Answer (score 4):

I gave up using `dconf` and tweak tool, I use kbindkeys with ~/.xbindkeysrc and put all my custom keyboard shortcuts, it is much more portable.

1. First install xbindkeys `$ sudo apt install xbindkeys`
2. Generate default .xbindkeysrc on the first time only, on the next time copy them to your home. `$ xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc`
3. Put your shortkeys on .xbindkeysrc, one example, use Ctrl+Shift+F to skip to the next music on spotify:

   ```
   "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next"
         m:0x19 + c:41
   ```
4. Other ex call gnome-calculator with Ctrl+Alt+Super+c put the line above in .xbindkeysrc:

   ```
         Control+Alt+Mod2+Mod4 + c
   ```

The xbindkeys format is easy, first line is the command and second line is the shortkey.

To discover the shortkey, use: `$ xbindkeys -k` and press the keys.

Remember to restart xbindkeys when add new shortkeys.

Comment: This does not seem to work in a Wayland session though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a new custom shortcut without a python script, by using sed.
You just have to set *name*, *binding* and *action* to your choice in the following script:

```
name="myaction"
binding="<CTRL><ALT>v"
action="/usr/local/bin/myaction"

media_keys=org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
custom_kbd=org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding
kbd_path=/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/$name/
new_bindings=`gsettings get $media_keys custom-keybindings | sed -e"s>'\]>','$kbd_path']>"| sed -e"s>@as \[\]>['$kbd_path']>"`
gsettings set $media_keys custom-keybindings "$new_bindings"
gsettings set $custom_kbd:$kbd_path name $name
gsettings set $custom_kbd:$kbd_path binding $binding
gsettings set $custom_kbd:$kbd_path command $action
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a script for that. See below.

See the usage in the `creatShortcut` invocation.

```bash
export nextShortcutId=0
function creatShortcut() {
    name="$1"
    commandToRun="$2"
    binding="$3"
    path="/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom${nextShortcutId}"
    nextShortcutId=$nextShortcutId+1
    dconf write "$path/name" "'""$name""'"
    dconf write "$path/command" "'""$commandToRun""'"
    dconf write "$path/binding" "'""$binding""'"
}

# dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding '"<Primary><Shift>exclam"'
creatShortcut 'copyq show' 'copyq show' '<Primary><Shift>exclam'
creatShortcut 'System Monitor' 'gnome-system-monitor' '<Primary><Alt>m'
creatShortcut 'Suspend' 'systemctl suspend -i' '<Super>d'
creatShortcut 'Volume Up' 'amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+' '<Super>Page_Up'
creatShortcut 'Volume Down' 'amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-' '<Super>Page_Down'

overallbindings=""
for ((i = 0 ; i < $nextShortcutId ; i++ ));
do
    overallbindings="$overallbindings, '$customindingPathPrefix$i/'"
done
overallbindings="[${overallbindings:2}]" # Delete the first 2 chars: " ," - space and comma
# echo $overallbindings

# Update the list of bindings for the shortcuts to work
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings "$overallbindings"
# dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/']"
```

Comment: It would be perfect if nextShortcutId could auto-detect if old keys are already there (already created by other programs) just to make certain that there are no conflicts. Also, check to see if anything else is bound to the entered keys.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/597414/279745) posted by @JacobVlijm very useful, especially the script. I ported the code to `bash`. I don’t think this function is perfect, it might contain some bugs, however, it works for me.

Don’t expect me to update this script here. You can find the latest version of the script (and all its revisions) [here](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/-/blob/master/bash/functions/gshort.sh).

```bsh
function set_shortcuts(){
    # Usage: set_shortcuts [name] [command] [shortcut]
    unset num i name command shortcut value test value_new
    local name="$1"
    local command="$2"
    local shortcut="$3"
    local value=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings)
    local test=$(echo $value | sed "s/\['//;s/', '/,/g;s/'\]//" - | tr ',' '\n' | grep -oP ".*/custom\K[0-9]*(?=/$)")

    if [ "$(echo "$value" | grep -o "@as")" = "@as" ]; then
        local num=0
        local value_new="['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom${num}/']"
    else
        local i=1
        until [ "$num" != "" ]; do
            if [ "$(echo $test | grep -o $i)" != "$i" ]; then
                local num=$i
            fi
            i=$(echo 1+$i | bc);
        done
        local value_new=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings | sed "s#']\$#', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom${num}/']#" -)
    fi

    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "$value_new"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom${num}/ name "$name"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom${num}/ command "$command"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom${num}/ binding "$shortcut"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python script which uses PyGObject bindings instead of calling `gsettings` and parsing the output. When a keybinding of the same name already exists, it replaces it instead of adding a duplicate.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from gi.repository import Gio, GLib

media_keys_schema = "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys"
custom_keybinding_schema = "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding"
keybinding_path_prefix = "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/"

usage_message = '''Usage: {cmd} <name> <command> <binding>

Example:
{cmd} "Open gedit" "gedit" "<Shift><Ctrl>G"
'''.format(cmd=sys.argv[0])


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 4:
        sys.exit(usage_message)
    name = sys.argv[1]
    command = sys.argv[2]
    binding = sys.argv[3]

    settings = Gio.Settings(schema=media_keys_schema)
    binding_paths = settings.get_value("custom-keybindings").unpack()  # type: list[str]

    # Figure out which path to use for the new binding. If a binding
    # of the same name already exists, we replace it.
    path = find(binding_paths, name)
    if not path:
        # Use the first gsettings path that doesn't exist yet
        n = 0
        path = keybinding_path_prefix + f"custom{n}/"
        while path in binding_paths:
            n += 1
            path = keybinding_path_prefix + f"custom{n}/"

    # Create the new keybinding
    setting = Gio.Settings(schema=custom_keybinding_schema, path=path)
    setting.set_string("name", name)
    setting.set_string("command", command)
    setting.set_string("binding", binding)
    setting.sync()

    if path not in binding_paths:
        # Add the new keybinding to the list of custom keybindings
        binding_paths.append(path)
        settings.set_value("custom-keybindings", GLib.Variant("as", binding_paths))
        setting.sync()


def find(binding_paths: list[str], name: str) -> str:
    for path in binding_paths:
        setting = Gio.Settings(schema=custom_keybinding_schema, path=path)
        setting_name = setting.get_value("name").unpack()
        if setting_name == name:
            return path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```