# How to open currently open VLC with shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, vlc, window-manager

I'm a new Linux user converting from windows. In windows, if I open vlc or other application use it, minimize and decide to run the application again by clicking on a file that is associated with it it will bring the application to the front and be in focus.

In ubuntu I have noticed with applications like nautilus, vlc and deluge that if I open the application the first time it brings it to the front with focus but if I minimize and then run it again by clicking on for instance a video file to launch vlc it starts playing in the background, the vlc icon shakes in the launcher but the application does not pop up.

Why on earth the ubuntu programmers hava decided to make it like this functionally I will never understand. If you know an easy fix for this please share.

Can I add a keyboard shortcut to open the currently open vlc player?

Answer (score 0):

I would install kubuntu-desktop, because kde is more friendly in my opinion.
If you want to give kde a try:

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Otherwise you need plugins to set your own hotkeys in unity:

All the custom keyboard shortcuts settings are stored in the dconf database.

You can easily access them with dconf-editor:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Then go to the following dconf path in the editor:

`/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/`

For more details see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by lowering your focus steal prevention level, to do this, first install compiz config settings manager, it can be done through the software center, or running:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

then launch it and go to general options > focus & raise behaviour > Focus prevention level; and set it to low or off, VLC raised for me ok with Low setting