# I don't seem to have the gnome-terminal

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, xterm

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, Ubuntu 16.04 opens xterm and when I search for `gnome-terminal` nothing is found. I searched for `terminal` and the only 2 applications there are XTerm and UXTerm.

How do I get the gnome terminal back?

Comment: @CollDue96 Alright, wasn't sure how that worked xD

Comment: according to some high-rep users saying on my recent meta post, you should accept one. Which one do you think is better quality? Provides more information? Is more detailed?

Comment: Perhaps expand on your answers a little?

Comment: Why are you having him un-accept an answer @CollDue96? What does it matter other than the question is answered, and the first who is accepted is chosen as the accepted answer? That's what helps everyone.

Comment: @PSmith, And don't pay attention to which one's first. Our goal is to fuel building a Q&A resource, not a how-fast-can-you-spew-an-answer contest. – SuperScript Jun 6 '15 at 19:11

Comment: Well I didn't say that at all, did I. I said "the first who is accepted". But I digress, I suppose it's best to leave an answer un-answered rather than to provide the documented correct answer for the rest of the community. It doesn't matter WHICH is accepted, but one needs to be, or else a new, correct answer written. Good luck, cheers.

Comment: Is the OP coming back

Comment: I agree. One dose need to be accepted. See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14069/which-answer-will-you-accept-when-both-answer-are-correct-but-expressed-in-diffe

Comment: Well he's already fixed his problem, revoked his acceptance, and has no reason to come back, but maybe, sometime. In the future, do not tell someone who asks a question not to accept an answer. It was never a contest; however, there are incentives, which is why we answer both quickly AND correctly. "Spewing" incorrect answers will leave that respondent with a lowered reputation anyway, thus resulting in fewer privileges. That will show for itself, and does not need any help from folks who instruct new users to **not** accept answers. That is, after all, the way the site works.

Comment: I feel bad giving anyone the best answer honestly XD but I'll give it to PSmith because his was first, it seems fair. Thank you guys, sorry for causing some confusion :)

Comment: Ah no worries, got to keep the Linux community stirred up a bit. Glad to be a part of it, and glad we could (both) help! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open any working terminal that you **do** have, and enter:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

You should be good to go!

You can also see this thread
[How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal)
as to how to set a custom key command, so that `CTRL` + `ALT` + `t` opens the terminal or program you choose, specifically, `gnome-terminal`.

So, for example, if you later choose to use `lily-term` or `xfce4-terminal` or something else, you may also change that keyboard shortcut/ command to open **that** terminal emulator, instead. In addition, you may set other commands to open other programs, such as `super` + `e` to open the file manager, or `CTRL` + `a` to open Audacity, etc, so long as those commands are not already in use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

This will install gnome-terminal.

Comment: Hopefully between us he gets it :D

Comment: Hopefully. I'll comment on him (because we posted so quickly in between each other) not to accept either.

Comment: I should have assumed that was the fix haha thanks guys, I get paranoid of other people making malicious packages that seem like main programs (not entirely sure if that happens) lol

Comment: @Fusiondew They aren't malicious programs.

Comment: Ah ok, wasn't sure but now I know! :D

Comment: haha @ CollDue96 I did comment first and I don't have many points yet! Close though! One needs to be accepted so this doesn't go "unanswered." Why tell him not to accept one? Also... @Fusiondew if a package comes from the repos and has the exact name, it's the real deal. Do a `sudo apt-cache search packagename` to check. You are normally safe; be wary using custom PPAs though, as one could possibly (not likely) leave something either careless or malicious in there somehow. Cheers!