# How can I find a specific custom key binding via its name?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dconf, gsettings

i can retrieve the list of custom key bindings by:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
```

which return something like:

```
['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/']
```

But i want to know target key binding via its name?
i.e. `shutter` -> `<primary><shift><alt>a`

I've figured out one simple but not convenient approach:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-  
keybinding:/org/gnome/settin‌​gs-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-  
keybindings/custom0/ name
// return the name like `shutter`


gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-  
keybinding:/org/gnome/settin‌​gs-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-  
keybindings/custom0/ binding
// return the binding like `<primary><shift><alt>a`
```

Does any guy know other elegant solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Small script to find the keybinding by name

The script below will output the keybinding when you run it with the shortcut's *name* as argument. an example:

```
$ python3 '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/find_keybinding.py' rename
> '<Primary><Alt>r'
```

#### How to set up

- Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `find_keybinding.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 '/path/to/find_keybinding.py' <shortcut_name>
  ```

#### Explanation

The information is in the output of

```
dconf dump /
```

On the custom keyboard shortcuts, this will output sections like:

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom9]
binding='<Primary><Alt>r'
command='/home/jacob/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/change_name'
name='rename'
```

As you can see, we need the line, two lines above

```
name='rename'
```

...and so the script outputs that line, stripped from `binding=`

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess; import sys
key = "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/"
# read the output from dconf dump /, split into lines
ls = [l for l in subprocess.check_output(["dconf", "dump", key]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()]
# find line corresponding to searched name, print two lines higher
print(ls[ls.index([l for l in ls if "name='"+sys.argv[1] in l][0])-2].replace("binding=", ""))
```

#### Additionally

...you could create the directory `~/bin` (if it doesn't exist yet) and save the script there *without extension*, and ***make it executable***. Log out and back in, then simply:

```
find_keybinding <name>
```

will do

Comment: Thank you anyway. That inspires me to implement the same thing through shell.

Comment: @SaintScott I got a (very long) oneliner, but the python option is more robust. Not a single exception on the weirdest names, name clashes etc.

Comment: sorry, i mean, through shell script, actually doing the similar thing like yours

Comment: @SaintScott I understand, that's what I did as well, I actually have one, but doing it in `python` turns out to be more straightforward and robust. Also, the question mentions no language preference :)

Comment: i'm not rejecting your answer, but just comment. :)

Comment: @SaintScott Not taken as such! I was just commenting on your comment :)

Comment: If @JacobVlijm's answer helped you, please take a moment to [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you!

Comment: @SaintScott ^ just curious, but is there a specific reason why you wouldn't accept it? Both the Q & A were kind of on your request, in the comments of this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/597414/72216

Comment: sorry, i'm a newbie to ask a question that i didn't realized that i should accept the answer. :(

Comment: @SaintScott thanks! Only if it solves your issue in a satisfying way :)

Comment: I have tried executing this script with a number of inputs, but keep getting the same result:


IndexError: list index out of range.

I am assuming no such binding exists. If so, can somebody harden the script?

Answer (score 0):

For custom keys try:

```
for i in $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings | awk -F"'" '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }'); do
    echo "$(dconf read ${i}binding) $(dconf read ${i}name)"
done
```

For other keys, grep over the following command:

```
for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas | grep -E 'keybindings|media-keys')
do
    gsettings list-recursively $schema
done
```

Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1477123/598062) for more.