# How can I find out which command/action is executed on a shortcut combination?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, xorg, dconf

I have created a custom shortcut and bound the `shutter -s` to it:

[image]

Then I tried to find out where this command is stored and checked settings by `dconf-editor`. But there are no information about the `shutter -s` bound command and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> combination:

[image]

**Thus, the questions**:

1. Where full information about key bindings is stored? Does a way exist to say: this key combination is using this command? For example, I want to see the default screenshot command which is executed on the <kbd>Print</kbd> press.
2. What happens when I press <kbd>Print</kbd> key? How this key press achieves a screenshot utility? For example:

   - some `tty` gets this key
   - GNOME Shell is connected to this `tty`, so it gets the key as input.
   - then GNOME Shell looks at some database (`dconf`?) and executes the command bound to the <kbd>Print</kbd> key.

I have read similar questions, like

- [How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4750/235025)
- [Where are GNOME keyboard shortcuts stored?](https://askubuntu.com/q/26056/235025)

but haven't found an answer to my questions.

Comment: did you have a look on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings

Comment: @db429 Yes. But haven't found answers to my questions there.

Comment: whats the output of bash-autocomplete (double pressing Tabulator) of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings `

Comment: @db429 Have used `gsettings` too. As well as I have looked at `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` before, through `dconf-editor`. Now, I run `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | less` and don't see bound commands.

Comment: @db429 `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` and double `Tab` does nothing.

Comment: well for the regular `PrintButton` command on my system I get quiet a lot with `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys | grep Print`

Comment: @db429 1) But these are just action names, aren't? Like `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot 'Print'`. I can't launch `screenshot` program from the `bash`. 2) Do you see any custom shortcuts, which mapped to a command with arguments, like `shutter -s`? For example, bind `libreoffice` to some key combination and try to find this shortcut by `gsettings`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, after alot of back-and-forth in the comments, I believe I  found the proper way to find the settings:

It is described in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings

**To find all (system) key bindings:**

lets just add all three mentioned commands:

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings ; gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys ; gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`

To find a special key you would pipe the output of each command through `grep -i <what you're looking for>` (the -i flag is to ignore case of letters) - so if you look for print it would look like this:

`gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | grep -i print ; gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys | grep -i print ; gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | grep -i print`

with some bash-magic this clearly could look nicer - but it works ;)

**Regarding custom Shortcuts**

> Custom Shortcuts
>
> Custom shortcuts are stored in dconf using a "relocatable schema". The
> schema name is
> "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding". Each
> custom key binding has three properties: name, command, and binding.
> Because of the relocatable schema, it is harder to use "gsettings"
> with custom shortcuts. Here is an example of getting the name of the
> first custom keybinding:
>
> `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name`

Please note, that the last part `custom0/`refers to the first custom set key binding.

With following command `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/` you'll get something like:

> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding command
> 'libreoffice'
> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding name
> 'libreoffice'
> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding binding
> 'l'

To find the correct entry you might have to increase the number in `custom0`.

To change e.g. the command use:

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command '<your command>'`

This will also work for `name` or `binding`.

To "clear" a custom key binding you could use:
`gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/`- this would clear the entries inside, yet the entry will still exist in the Gnome-Settings as empty entry, but are 'deactivated', sort of.

**How it works with gsettings - the second question:**
Have a look here: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html

Good Night and Good Luck! ;)

Comment: Thanks, now I have found `shutter -s` too. But what about default screenshot application? I can launch it through `Show Application` button by typing `screenshot` in the search bar. So, it looks like a separate program and it should be bound to `Print` key somehow, because when I press `Print` key, the same application is running. My initial purpose was to find the name of this default application and see its command arguments, which is executed on `Print` press. Then I want to launch it by `bash`.

Comment: It seems, that default screenshot application is different from standalone applications like `libreoffice` or `shutter`, maybe it is Gnome extension and can be launched by GUI only. And `screencast` utility the same.

Comment: I looked into the [Gnome Shell source](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/mainline/src/shell-screenshot.c) and it approves that I have said in the previous comment. This is why I couldn't find a default `screenshot` program - because it is built-in Gnome Shell's functionality.

Comment: @MiniMax "My initial purpose was to find the name of this default application and see its command arguments, which is executed on Print press. Then I want to launch it by bash. " You never wrote that. - I would appreciate if you'd mark this question as solved.

Comment: It was written in the 1-st question ;).

Comment: @MiniMax you were asking about key bindings (and used screenshot functionality as exampple) - not about how to use screenshot functionality in a script - or am I mistaken?

Comment: Generally, I wanted a way to determine which command is bound to some arbitrary shortcut. Custom and default. To be able to see a command's name and passed options. And we have solved this task: you found out custom shortcuts storage scheme, I found out that default Gnome applications (`screenshot`, `screencast`) are built-in. The second question was auxiliary. So, now I have known what I wanted, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For custom keybindings the command is:

```
for i in $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings | awk -F"'" '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }'); do
    echo "$(dconf read ${i}binding) $(dconf read ${i}command)"
done
```

For a specific custom keybinding, try:

```
for i in $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings | awk -F"'" '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }'); do
    echo "$(dconf read ${i}binding) $(dconf read ${i}command)"
done | grep -i '<Super>A'
```

For other keybinding, the command is:

```
for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas |  grep -E 'keybindings|media-keys')
do
 gsettings list-recursively $schema
done
```

To find out what a specific key is bound to (not custom commands), run:

```
for schema in $(gsettings list-schemas | grep -E 'keybindings|media-keys')
do
    gsettings list-recursively $schema 
done | grep -i '<Primary><Super>Up'
```