# How to change shortcuts via command-line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, shortcuts

I want to write a bash script which would change keyboard shortcuts (for System). I don't want to use GUI for this purpose.

Does anybody know how to do it using command-line only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal)

Comment: Not exactly. In this link people told about CUSTOM shortcuts.
I want to change system shortcuts like Alt + LEFT, Alt + F8. After that I can easy use products from jetBrains like Idea and PHPStotrm