# Determine current keyboard shortcuts in gnome-terminal using gsettings

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, gsettings

I am using gnome-terminal version 3.20.2 with Ubuntu 16.10. I would like to determine the current keybindings in Gnome Terminal for switching to next tab using `gsettings`. This is similar to what is done in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/597414/156688) answer for the Unity desktop.

From the menu in gnome-terminal I can change the key binding by selecting `Terminal->Preferences->Shortcuts` and then scrolling down to the `Tabs` heading and then clicking "Switch to Next Terminal". From this menu I can also see that my current binding is `Ctrl+Right`. How can I determine this binding from the command line using the `gsettings` command?

**Edit**:

I tried:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/ next-tab
'<Control>Page_Down'
```

but this gives the default binding `Ctrl+PageDown`; I would like to get the current binding, which is `Ctrl+Right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297660/45537) answer. It seems like a full path must be given:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ next-tab
'<Primary>Right'
```

I am not sure how to determine the full path for a relocatable schema (I simply copied the code from the above linked answer and it worked), if anyone can explain this better please feel free to edit this question or provide your own answer. It would also be interesting to know why **not** specifying a full path will give you the default value for the keybinding.

Also note that `<Primary>` refers to the `Ctrl` key, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168505/45537) question for more information.