# Map "CTRL+ENTER" to another key inside gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

### Intro

**Is there any way of  mapping `CTRL+ENTER` to an `F`-key?** *(Inside the terminal ofcourse only)* I've looked everywhere, I've tried so many things that I can't even recall. I had no luck and so I decide to replace `gnome-terminal` with `Alacritty` but still I'm left with the question.

### Related Sources

- ***`gnome-terminal` (oriented):***
- - [[intrepid] equivalent of XTerm*VT100.translations: string with gnome-terminal](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2008-November/165035.html)
- - [Bug#899376: gnome-terminal: Ctrl-Shift-Enter/Ctrl-Enter](https://linux.debian.bugs.dist.narkive.com/QGsloxri/bug-899376-gnome-terminal-ctrl-shift-enter-ctrl-enter-in-mc-isn-t-working-on-wayland)
- - [Add custom shortcut to the GNOME Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129452/add-custom-shortcut-to-the-gnome-terminal)
- - [gnome-terminal .Xdefaults](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=128328)

> Gnome-terminal doesn't use Xresources / Xdefaults to store its settings, therefore if you want Xdefaults' look in gnome-terminal you have to 'tune' it accordingly manually. Look under the valid menu entry to customize your colours and enter the values from your Xdefaults file.

- - [Ctrl-Enter, Shift-Enter and Enter are interpreted as the same key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536373/492431)

> KDE or Gnome applications like konsole and gnome-terminal have their own way of configuring key combos to actions; I don't know if that includes the ability to write arbitrary strings to the pseudo-tty master.

- - [How to bind CTRL + Enter in zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45714460/11465149)

> Here is the solution for xterm, gnome-terminal and any other terminal emulator for the XWindow system.

- - **Slightly related thing i came across:**
- - - [Determine current keyboard shortcuts in gnome-terminal using gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879104/determine-current-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-terminal-using-gsettings)
- - - [Configuring gnome terminal programmatically](https://ncona.com/2019/11/configuring-gnome-terminal-programmatically/)
- - - [Where are Gnome-Terminal profiles stored in the filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72684/where-are-gnome-terminal-profiles-stored-in-the-filesystem)
- - - [gnome-terminal - restoring of config for profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491191/gnome-terminal-restoring-of-config-for-profiles)
- - - [Add a custom keybinding with gsettings in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527990/add-a-custom-keybinding-with-gsettings-in-ubuntu)
- ***Other Terminal (oriented):***
- - [How to map Shift-Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461580/11465149)
- - [CTRL+ENTER on Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633786/11465149)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VTE, and thus GNOME Terminal, doesn't allow to modify the escape sequences that the keyboard's keys generate.

You can modify them in VTE's source code in `src/keymap.cc`, or I guess it's also possible to patch GNOME Terminal to grab the combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before it would reach VTE and instead send whatever you want to send.

Maybe (I'm not sure) you can find and configure an `xbindkeys`-like app to mangle the keycode just for one particular application.

Or of course switching to a different terminal emulator is also a possibility.