# Custom keyboard shortcut creation limited

Tags: 18.04, bash, shortcut-keys, customization

I'm learning about bash script by writing one to setup all (or most of) my Ubuntu 18.04 customization. One of these are my keyboard shortcuts.

I'm using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/826328/689894) strategy to config the hotkeys. However I observed it is accepting just the first 8 custom shortcuts I setup.
I mean, the hotkeys that I store between `custom0` and `custom7` slots had been saved, but all others ignored.

Do someone have a clue about what could been happening?

> This is the scripting I'm using:

```
# Terminal
$(dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/next-tab "'<Alt>w'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/prev-tab "'<Alt>a'")

# Music
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/play "'<Super>KP_Separator'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/next "'<Super>KP_Decimal'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/previous "'<Super>KP_Divide'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/volume-up "'<Super>KP_Add'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/volume-down "'<Super>KP_Subtract'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/volume-mute "'<Super>KP_Multiply'")

# Launch
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/www "'<Primary><Alt>c'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/home "'<Primary><Alt>f'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/binding "'<Primary><Alt>k'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/command "'gnome-control-center keyboard'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/name "'Shortcuts settings'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/binding "'<Primary><Alt>equal'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/command "'env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/gnome-calculator_gnome-calculator.desktop /snap/bin/gnome-calculator %U'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/name "'Calculator'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/binding "'<Primary><Alt>a'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/command "'atom ~/.fragatron'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/name "'Atom'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/binding "'<Primary><Alt>y'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/command "'/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=eeaafbmfeofhhjpjklgoobllogkjdgap'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/name "'YouTube Music'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/binding "'<Primary><Alt>z'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/command "'/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=lilmhcaoekddncecbphbjdbjccdbneij'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/name "'Google Tradutor'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/binding "'<Primary><Alt>g'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/command "'/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=mmlonmkggdiafehdajlempfflcdfddna'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/name "'GitHub'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/binding "'<Primary><Alt>KP_Separator'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/command "'toggle-sound-output'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/name "'Toggle sound-output'")

$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/binding "'<Primary><Shift>KP_1'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/command "'profile-info name'")
$(dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/name "'Profile Name'")
```

Comment: can you edit your question and add the script part containing all the keyboard shortcuts for checking it/reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, the answer was simpler then expected. For some reason, in Ubuntu
>   18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver, I can not set more than nine custom shortcuts just writing them as shown.

To solve this, just overwrite the `custom-keybindings` attribute with the whole list of custom shortcuts:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "[\
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom1/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom2/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom3/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom4/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom5/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom6/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom7/', \
  '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybinding/custom8/' \
]"
```

I tried this even using different names (non-numbered) for each custom keybinding and it worked without problems.

> I register it here hoping it would help someone!