# List all GNOME shortcuts currently in use

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I am trying to set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start an application, but that shortcut is not recognized. I guess it is already in use somehow, but I don't see it in the list of shortcuts and when I press it nothing happens. Is there a way to list all shortcuts currently in use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut - get a list of what is already used?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128705/keyboard-shortcut-get-a-list-of-what-is-already-used)

Comment: @vanadium Thanks for the hint. I updated the question. I am looking for all GNOME shortcuts, not application level shortcuts.

Comment: They are stored in different places. Not as such possible to draw a complete list with a single command. Anyway, I am using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to launch the terminal without issue.

Answer (score 7):

Open a shell as current user and run:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by randomly killing applications until the shortcut was available again. It looks there was an update of an (internal) application that decided to consume the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to search your keyboard shortcuts by pressing the magnifying glass button while in the settings menu. Not quite a list, but at least you can see what is in use.

However I think this won't solve your problem. Not all key combinations are valid for custom shortcuts, and I don't think '+t' is allowed. A user posted some limits [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178745/is-there-any-known-way-to-get-around-the-limitations-of-the-gnome-custom-key-bin), but I haven't seen an exhaustive list of what is or isn't permitted.

Comment: I updated my question. The word `Super` was not shown, I guess because I put it in angle brackets. Thanks for the link anyway, I wasn't aware that there were limits to shortcuts that can be used.

Comment: @jens glad it was a little helpful. I would have just commented if I had enough rep...